# How to get value="x" from html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="progres-bar" class="progres-bar" value="90"></div>
```

I want to get value from this element where `value="90"`, so the output should be `90` using javascript. I tried to make this with the below way:

```
document.getElementById("progres-bar").value;
```

but it didn't worked!

Comment: Technically a `<div>` doesn't *have* a `value`.  Semantically what you probably want instead is `data-value="90"`, which would make the usage more explicit as well.  Browsers may be forgiving of what you're doing here and it may "work", but it's always better to start with valid markup instead of relying on browsers handling invalid markup correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` function.

```js
const value = document.getElementById("progres-bar").getAttribute("value");
console.log(value);
```

```html
<div id="progres-bar" class="progres-bar" value="90"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please create a snippet that includes OP's html to show the result of your code?

Comment: @0stone0 updated code, please check.